# Convert 2^n to numeric value in python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a line in python and use the log base scale on the axis. However, I would like the values to be displayed as numeric values instead of 2^n, i.e. 2^1 should be displayed as 2, 2^2 as 4 and so on. Is it possible to change these values?

This is my current code for plotting:

```html
 # plot the line
 plt.plot(labeled_samples, result, color='black', label='Normal SVM', marker='*')
 #plt.plot(, color='black', label = 'Polynomial', marker='o')
 plt.legend(loc="upper right")
 plt.ylim([0.05, 0.5])
 plt.yticks(np.arange(0.05, 0.55, 0.05))
 plt.xscale('log', basex=2)
 plt.xlabel('Nb of labeled points')
 plt.ylabel('Test error')
 set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
 plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do so: Modify the tick labels on the x-axis using integer values. You failed to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I am using some test data

```
x = np.logspace(1, 7, 7, base=2, dtype=int)
y = x**0.05
plt.plot(x, y, color='black', label='Normal SVM', marker='*')
plt.legend(loc="upper right")

plt.xscale('log', basex=2)
plt.xlabel('Nb of labeled points')
plt.ylabel('Test error')
plt.xticks(x, x);
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!